# Update rows on one MySQL table where rows with a matching column exist on another table?

Tags: php, mysql, join, compare

I have two tables ("z" and "z_ao"). "z" contains all the zip codes in the U.S. along with other needed information. "z_ao" contains only certain zip codes. I want to set the "ls" column to "1" in every row in "z" where "zip" in "z" matches "zip" in "z_ao".

I have been reading all day to determine the "right" way of doing this, which I think would make use of JOIN but got frustratingly confused and in this case this was a one-time operation so I finally did things the following clumsy, query-intensive way:

```
$z = mysql_query("SELECT zip_code FROM z");
while($z_row = mysql_fetch_row($z)) {
  $zao = mysql_query("SELECT zip FROM z_ao WHERE zip='$z_row[0]'");
  $zao_num=mysql_numrows($zao);
  if (mysql_numrows($zao) == 1) {
    mysql_query("UPDATE z SET ls = '1' WHERE zip_code='$z_row[0]'");
  }
}
```

I'm sorry to ask for help because I know the answer is out there but for future reference, I would like to understand what would have been the proper way to do this and I think I need to see an exact example.

Thank you.

Comment: You should really be asking `How do I make my table/column names less cryptic and almost impossible to analyze?` You should also look into normalization as this appears to violate that.

Comment: I apologize if my database and naming conventions offend your intellectual sensibilities. I am doing my best here. Next time I desire wit and sarcasm more than help I will address my question to you specifically.

The 'z_ao' table was to be deleted once this was done. 'z' an 'z_ao' were never intended to coexist.

Comment: When do you not desire wit and sarcasm? ;) No need to apologize (unless that, too, was sarcasm). I was just having a little fun with your naming. No malice intended. In all seriousness, more descriptive names are always better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try a multi-table UPDATE:

```
UPDATE z INNER JOIN z_ao ON z.zip_code = z_ao.zip SET z.ls='1'
```

You don't need to do any counts or tests or loops.  The JOIN matches rows for you, and automatically excludes zip codes that have no match in your z_ao table.

Comment: Beautiful and fast! Thanks a lot! I was certain this could be done somehow with JOIN and no counting or loops and I thank you for providing it.

Answer (score 2):

how about IN...

```
update z set ls = 1 where zip_code IN ( select zip_code from z_ao );
```

Comment: this will update everything. You need to add where in subquery

Comment: @Andrey: You are incorrect. It will only update `z` if there is a corresponding row in `z_ao`.